# VueJS returns undefined in created function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i have started working on a small project using VueJs, i've made a get request using Axios library which returns some data as expected, but I cannot call loadUsers function using this inside mounted
this is my code:

```
export default{
  data(){
     return {
        users : {}
     }
  },
  methods:{
     addCustomer(){
        //var form = document.querySelector('#add-customer');
        var formData = $('#add-customer').serialize();
        axios.post('/Thirdparty', formData).then(function(response){
           helper.validation(response.data);
           //alert(response.data.error);
        });
     },
     loadUsers(){
        axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then(function(data){
           this.users = data.data;
        });
     }
  },
  created(){
     let self=this
     self.loadUsers(); 
  }
}
```

as you can see also i've used self variable to call my loadUsers() function, but i'm still getting 
this is undefined error

Comment: You need to do `let self=this;` in `loadUsers()`  before doing the axios call, not in `created()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing `this.users` within the callback to `axios.get().then()` in `loadUsers()`. Due to you're using a standard function and not an arrow function, `this` is not referring to the Vue instance, i.e. the scope for `this` is now incorrect. Either use an arrow function or change the reference:

```js
// Do this...
export default{
  data(){
     return {
        users : {}
     }
  },
  methods:{
     addCustomer(){
        //var form = document.querySelector('#add-customer');
        var formData = $('#add-customer').serialize();
        axios.post('/Thirdparty', formData).then(function(response){
           helper.validation(response.data);
           //alert(response.data.error);
        });
     },
     loadUsers(){
        axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then((data) => { // Using an arrow function.
           this.users = data.data;
        });
     }
  },
  created(){
     let self=this
     self.loadUsers(); 
  }
}

// Or this...
export default{
  data(){
     return {
        users : {}
     }
  },
  methods:{
     addCustomer(){
        //var form = document.querySelector('#add-customer');
        var formData = $('#add-customer').serialize();
        axios.post('/Thirdparty', formData).then(function(response){
           helper.validation(response.data);
           //alert(response.data.error);
        });
     },
     loadUsers(){
        let self=this; // Adding "self"
        axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then(function(data){
           self.users = data.data; // Referencing "self" instead of "this".
        });
     }
  },
  created(){
     let self=this
     self.loadUsers(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @connexo Yeah, I noticed that just a moment ago and started fixing it. Thanks for pointing it out, though :)

Comment: So, after applying either of the fixes, is `let self = this` in `created()` even necessary?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Not one bit.